# В @OneToMany и @ManyToOne аннотации у меня ID null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Который день бьюсь с проблемой: при работе с двухнапраленной зависимостью, колонка `customer_id` в сущности `PhoneNumber` выдает null при добавлении в БД. Все данные нормально записываются, но в `customer_id` не передается id из БД `Customer`.

**Customer.java**:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private long id;

    //некоторый код...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**PhoneNumber.java**:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "phoneNumber")
public class PhoneNumber {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "phone_id")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your phone number")
    private String phoneNumber;
}
```

P.S. для сохранения объектов использую [.save()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-persistence.saving-entites) метод

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов решения данной проблемы (может не совсем правильный, но работающий):

**Customer.java**:

```java
/*
Код
*/

 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name="cust_addr_id")
 private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();

/*
Код
*/
```

**PhoneNumber.java**:

```java
/*
Код
*/

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="cust_pn_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
  private Customer customer;

/*
Код
*/
```